Creating multiple figures with different color OpenGl
I have code that creates multiple I-beams in different position when i try to make every beam have random color it paint wrong part in wrong color
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    import random

    # size of figure
    m = 5

    vertices = (
        # up
        (-0.4, 0.22),  # A0
        (0.3, 0.5),    # G1
        (0.1, 0.22),   # M2
        (0.8, 0.5),    # N3
        # down
        (-0.4, -0.25),  # F4
        (0.3, 0.05),    # Z5
        (0.1, -0.25),   # K6
        (0.8, 0.05),    # S7
        # front
        (-0.4, 0.12),   # B8
        (-0.2, 0.12),   # C9
        (-0.2, -0.15),  # D10
        (-0.4, -0.15),  # E11
        (0.1, 0.12),    # L12
        (-0.1, 0.12),   # H13
        (-0.1, -0.15),  # I14
        (0.1, -0.15),   # J15
        # back
        (0.3, 0.4),   # O16
        (0.5, 0.4),   # Q17
        (0.5, 0.15),  # V18
        (0.3, 0.15),  # W19
        (0.8, 0.4),   # P20
        (0.6, 0.4),   # R21
        (0.6, 0.15),  # U22
        (0.8, 0.15),  # T23
    )

    edges = ((0, 1),
         (0, 8),
         (1, 3),
         (1, 16),
         (2, 3),
         (2, 12),
         (3, 20),
         (4, 5),
         (4, 6),
         (4, 11),
         (5, 7),
         (5, 19),
         (6, 7),
         (6, 15),
         (7, 23),
         (16, 17),
         (17, 18),
         (18, 19),
         (20, 21),
         (21, 22),
         (22, 23),
         (8, 16),
         (8, 9),
         (9, 17),
         (0, 2),
         (10, 18),
         (10, 11),
         (11, 19),
         (9, 10),
         (12, 13),
         (13, 14),
         (14, 15),
         (12, 20),
         (13, 21),
         (14, 22),
         (15, 23))


    def random_color():
        return (random.random(), random.random(), random.random())

    figures = []
    max_figures = 2

    def I_beam(x, y, scale, color1, color2):
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        for i, edge in enumerate(edges):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                glColor3fv(color1)  # change red
            else:
                glColor3fv(color2)  # change blue
            glVertex2f((vertices[edge[0]][0] + x) * scale, (vertices[edge[0]][1] + y) * scale)
            glVertex2f((vertices[edge[1]][0] + x) * scale, (vertices[edge[1]][1] + y) * scale)
        glEnd()

    def main():
        pygame.init()
        display = (900, 600)
        pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)

        gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -10)

        while len(figures) < max_figures:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

            for figure in figures:
                I_beam(figure[0], figure[1], m, figure[2], figure[3])

            if len(figures) < max_figures:
                x = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
                y = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
                color1 = random_color() # new color
                color2 = random_color() # new color
                figures.append((x, y, color1, color2))  # add to list

            pygame.display.flip()

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

            for figure in figures:
                I_beam(figure[0], figure[1], m, figure[2], figure[3])

            pygame.display.flip()


In some parts it looks like i just need change positions of edges like(12-13) and (21,20) but another parts cannot be solved by this logic
connections
How it do
How it must`

glBegin/glEnd sequences are not part of OpenGL ES 2.0
